# JSON KENDO DataSource External search filter not working

Tags: jquery, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using external search filter for kendo grid..

My code data source read function it will return json data

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type        : 'json',
                transport   : {
                    read:  {
                        url: apiurl+"/customer/getCustomers",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{'userID':userID}
                    }                   
                },
});
```

My search function

```
var customerID   = $("#customerID").val();

grid.dataSource.query({
                page:1,
                pageSize:10,
                filter:{
                    logic:"and",
                    filters:[
                        {field:"uniqueID", operator:"contains",value:customerID},

                    ]
                }
            });
```

The above code i have used for filter query

These below json response only i will receive

```
{"status":true,"code":1,"message":"Success","api":"getCustomers","result":{"customer":[{"uniqueID"
:11},{"uniqueID"
:12},{"uniqueID"
:13}..]}
```

But the filter query not filter as per the condition..the filter always return all response data..not filters data ..ie if i search 5 in customer id field ..it returns everything

It's only occurring for json data response

Comment: What data are you receving (..... doesn't really help) and how does the data get filtered on the server side?

Comment: Can you please include a complete, representative set of data?  Your filter is using `uniqueID`, but I don't see that in the snippet of data you provided.

Comment: @whipdancer..i have edited

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf... i need to filter the datasource using filter kendo grid...my response is json data